# How to access the "Custom Content View" of a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an app that uses a `UINavigationController` to control its flow, and I want to be able to dynamically swap views into and out of one of the pages in my app.  The UINavigationController Reference from Apple's Docs shows **[this diagram outlining the structure of a UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**.

So my question is this:  from within the currently-displayed `UIViewController`, how do I access the area labeled as "Your custom content here" to determine its frame/size and how do I swap content into and out of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's your custom content, you will create the view that contains it, either in Interface Builder or by manually coding it.  See the [docs for loadView:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1) and look at some of the sample code.  You'll want a root view whose subviews you swap about as you described.  At which point, Justin's comment about self.view is appropriate.